# How to access the following json code using jsp?

Tags: json, facebook, jsp

```
 {
  "likes": {
    "data": [{
      "id": "122032077982945"//id
    }, {
      "id": "307083702751174"//id
    }, {
      "id": "197394889304"
    }]
  }
}
```

I want to access facebook data. Basically I want to print all the like of the user in the webpage.How to access the following json code using jsp?  How should I do this?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? We need to know a little more about your architecture first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing AJAX call from the JSP page to the server side and receive that data, you can parse them by using JavaScript and jQuery:

```
var likesData = jQuery.parseJSON('{"likes": {"data": [{"id": "122032077982945"}, {"id": "307083702751174"}, {"id": "197394889304"}]}}').likes.data;

for (var idx in likesData) {           
   console.log("likeID: " + likesData[idx].id);
}
```

You'll get:

```
likeID: 122032077982945
likeID: 307083702751174
likeID: 197394889304
```